# see if there is a capcha to solve post request c#

Tags: c#, request, http-post, recaptcha, captcha

I'm doing multiples post requests on a website and I would like to know how can I know if there is a captcha to solve?

I there is one I want to open a window and the person behind the computer will solve it.
if there isn't any captcha the program continues.

Here is the code of the website: 
[image]

I don't understand very much of captcha but I know there is a data-site-key that i need to use and the g-recaptcha-response to get. But I have no idea what to do with those...

In the form I need to pass a g-recaptcha-response.

thank you all for the help

Comment: See the ReCaptcha documentation.

Comment: @SLaks already did... I wouldn't be posting if I didn't

Comment: We need more info to really help. Are you site scraping the pages prior to doing any posts? Are you simply sending a POST to an endpoint and prior to doing so, you're trying to see if you need to look for a Captcha? It would help to see the code your currently trying to use to perform the POST.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My code Is huge that's why I can't post it here... 
So i'll try to answer the most precisely I can. My programs adds an item to cart and checkouts. First, I scrape the website looking for what item i need, then I do a post request (no captcha here) to add to bag. then i go to checkout and do a post request to put my infos (CC / address). at this point it's possible there is a recaptcha, but it's not always the case. I want to know how could I know if there is a recaptcha to solve or not

Comment: @SLaks my question is: How can I know if there is a recaptcha to solve ? sometimes there is no captcha to solve sometimes there is

Comment: Look at the response and see whether those tags are there?

Comment: On my computer the captcha never appears so nop I can do that :/